# How to use a collada model with aframe-v1.1.0.min

Tags: aframe, collada, webxr

I have been using a-frame since 2018 to show my scenographies to the directors I work for. I used the colladas files for my objects and everything was working great and my textures were
as I wanted. But since the webxr (aframe-v1.1.0.min) appeared it is no longer possible to use
collada I have tried the Gltf files but it is too heavy and not satisfactory. So I wanted to know how to put collada back into the a-frame scipts. I tried: "collada-model-legacy.js"
with "ColladaLoader.js" in another folder but it doesn't work. Do you have a solution?
Thank you

Comment: glTF is now the recommended format. You can convert easily with https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF

Comment: thank you for your answer, but collada is more than a format for me, it is graphically and artistically more interesting especially for the matt side of the colors and the materials and I do not need the animation. Gltf is too heavy and too bright and there is a lot of aliaising (even with anti-aliaising enabled) I really want to keep collada, is there really no way ??? thank you in advance

Comment: COLLADA is not suited for real time applications but an exchange format for 3D applications. glTF is designed to be quick to parse an load by an engine. Analogy with 2D images is that COLLADA is PSD while glTF would be PNG. glTF should be lighter weight than COLLADA. glTF doesn't prescribe aliasing and brightness. Maybe the way you're loading the model or lighting the scene is affecting how the model looks. Worth opening separate questions for those issues. Best of luck

Comment: Thank you. I understand and you are probably right, but let me insist. I worked for a long time to develop a workflow with collada, 
and now it's junk. Collada is enough for me and I want to keep it. Please give me a way to continue using it with webxr and a-frame. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the loaders from the three.js repository - also the [ColladaLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js).

You could create a wrapper component, which will use threejs loader and add the model to the scene:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    const el = this.el;
    // create a loader
    const loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    // load the model
    loader.load("MODEL_URL", function(model) {
      el.object3D.add(collada.scene);
    })
  }
})
```

A simple example could be [this component](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/aframe/collada) (check it out with static and animated collada models [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/collada/))

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much. I will be able to continue to use collada with the fabulous a-frame, but that will not prevent me from continuing to explore the gltf format which promises. Thanks again...